# How change methane injectors on Zafira 2004 CNG engine?

Tags: fuel-injectors, zafira, cng

What is the process to change CNG injectors on a 2004 Zafira? What has to be disconnected?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!